# struct with template member function cannot be used as template param unless using template deduction

Tags: c++, templates

Below code block won't compile when invoking template member function (on template parameter) without taking advantage template argument deduction. Can someone point out what I'm missing here, TIA.

```
struct Foo
{
    template<typename T>
    void set(const T& thing) { }
};

template<typename T>
class Bar 
{
public:
    Bar() {
        // struct Foo declared 
        f.set(5);       // compiles
        f.set<int>(5);  // compiles

        // struct Foo via template parameter type T
        t.set(5);       // compiles
        t.set<int>(5);  // doesn't compile
    }

    Foo f;
    T t;
};

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Bar<Foo> b;
}
```

Code also available at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50294c63b3acdef9

Comment: Make it `t.template set<int>(5)`. For all the compiler knows, `t.set` is a data member, and `<` that follows is a less-than operator. `template` keyword is necessary to tell the compiler that `set` is in fact a template. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011740/the-template-disambiguator-for-dependent-names

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think you should post that as an answer!

Comment: Thank you @IgorTandetnik!  Makes complete sense.